# Stream the computer audio output (possible video screen too) to a physical device

Tags: windows, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I'm looking for a solution (software and hardware) that allows me to stream the computer audio and possibly the video too to a device which I can connect to my stereo or TV.

I'm not interested in solutions based on AirPlay since this requires you to use iTunes.

Other solutions use VLC – the thing is: Those do stream content (a file), but I want to stream the  general audio output, so if I'm watching a YouTube video (or Vimeo, or a Skype call) I want to hit a button and then I have the sound sent to my stereo.

Comment: Good question.  I have a similar problem.  I can stream the audio from my laptop to my TV by plugging an audio cable into my laptop's audio out jack at one end and into the audio input on my TV set at the other end.  I can do the same thing with the video.  Now my problem is, how do I turn the audio off on the laptop's local speaker?

Comment: On windows open the audio mixer and turn down the volume of the pc a turn up the audio output.

Comment: @WalterMitty, you should probably post a new question about that.

Comment: Maybe I will.  But I think a good answer to this question will probably work for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Oh, you're using Windows. Rewritten Windows answer:

There *is* actually an Airplay-based solution: the **AirParrot** application (http://airparrot.com/) combined with a 2nd-gen or newer Apple TV can mirror your screen and audio like you want to, but an Apple TV isn't that cheap. (The software is available for Windows XP and up, but I don't know how well-written it is.)

Probably a better (cheaper, more-supported) option, if your computer supports it, is Intel Wireless Display, or  [**WiDi**](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-wireless-display.html). [Here's an example](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122508) of a WiDi box that you can hook up to your TV (or if you have a really new TV or set-top box, it might have a WiDi receiver built-in already). However, you need a WiDi-enabled computer to use this solution.

---

(and in case there *are* mac users browsing this question wanting the same thing: use [Airplay Mirroring](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5404) if you have a newer Mac+AppleTV, it's free! And use [AirParrot](http://airparrot.com/) if you have an *older* mac and newer AppleTV.)

Comment: The OP uses Windows.